# How to create rate on R

Tags: r, lm, rate

I want to change my data so that it gives me the rate of pedestrians to that states population. I am using a linear model and my summary values look like this:
Coefficients:

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  0.087061   0.029876   2.914  0.00438 **
intersection 0.009192   0.003086   2.978  0.00362 **
```

Here, my beta value intersection is .009192 and that is not meaningful because compared to a state that has a smaller population, this value might be nothing in comparison.

Below is a condensed version of my data without all the columns I use, but here is the link of the csv incase someone wants to download it from [there](https://www.nhtsa.gov/content/nhtsa-ftp/280561).

```
> head(c)
# A tibble: 6 x 15
  STATE STATENAME  PEDS PERSONS PERMVIT PERNOTMVIT COUNTY COUNTYNAME     CITY   DAY MONTH  YEAR LATITUDE LONGITUD
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 Alabama       0       3       3          0     81 LEE (81)       2340     7     2  2019     32.7    -85.3
2     1 Alabama       0       2       2          0     55 ETOWAH (55)    1280    23     1  2019     34.0    -86.1
3     1 Alabama       0       4       4          0     29 CLEBURNE (29)     0    22     1  2019     33.7    -85.4
4     1 Alabama       1       1       1          1     55 ETOWAH (55)    2562    22     1  2019     34.0    -86.1
5     1 Alabama       0       1       1          0      3 BALDWIN (3)       0    18     1  2019     30.7    -87.8
6     1 Alabama       0       2       2          0     85 LOWNDES (85)      0     7     1  2019     32.2    -86.4
# … with 1 more variable: FATALS <dbl>
```

Here is the code I have that runs through the process I am doing. I don't see how I can change it so that each value is a rate (values like peds or type_int)

```
#Libraries
rm(list=ls()) # this is to clear anything  in memory
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(htmltools)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(mapproj)
library(mapdata)
library(zoo)
library(tsibble)

setwd("~/Desktop/Statistics790/DataSets/FARS2019NationalCSV")
df <- read.csv("accident.csv")

state <- unique(df$STATE)
for(i in state){
  df1<- df %>%
    filter(STATE==i) %>%
    dplyr::select(c(STATE,PEDS,DAY,MONTH,YEAR,TYP_INT)) %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(as.character(paste(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, sep = "-"),"%Y-%m-%d"))) %>% # create a date
    group_by(date) %>% # Group by State id and date
    # summarise_at(.vars = vars(PEDS), sum)
    summarise(pedday=sum(PEDS),intersection=mean(TYP_INT))
#ts1<-ts(df,start=c(2019,1,1), frequency=365) 
setwd("~/Desktop/Statistics790/States_ts/figures")
plots<-df1 %>% 
    ggplot()+
    geom_line(aes(x=date,y=pedday))+ylim(0,13)+
    theme_bw()
    ggsave(paste0("state_",i,".png"),width=8,height=6, )
  ts1<-ts(df1,start=c(2019,1,1), frequency=365)
  setwd("~/Desktop/Statistics790/States_ts")
  ts1 %>% write.csv(paste0("state_",i,".csv"),row.names = F)
#Plots
}
#date1<- as.character(df$date)
#df1<- df%>% filter(STATE=="1")
#ts2<-xts(df,order.by = as.Date(df$date,"%Y-%m-%d"))
setwd("~/Desktop/Statistics790/States_ts")
cat("\f")
#df <- read.csv(paste0("state_1.csv"))
#print("------Linear Model------")
#summary(lm(pedday~weather,data=df))

for(i in state){
  print(paste0("-------------------------Analysis for State: ",i," -------------------------------"))
  df <- read.csv(paste0("state_",i,".csv"))
  print("------Linear Model------")
  print(summary(lm(pedday~intersection,data=df)))
}
```

Comment: Do you want the rate of PEDS vs PERSONS? If so it's just `df$rate <- df$PEDS / df$PERSONS`. And if you want it as a percentage you can add `* 100`.

Comment: Hello Elle, I wanted to have pedestrians/population, where population would depend on the state. I have 51 states here and pedestrian values for each state. I do not have a population total column here, I would need to get it from an outside source but I do not know where to start with this @Elle

Comment: Perhaps you could get them from the Census website https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-state-total.html#par_textimage_1574439295 and then do something like `left_join(df, census, by = c('State'))`.

Comment: Ah I see what you are suggesting but I would need to left_join to every state, since each gets processed as its own csv and I am confused on the steps to take to do that @Elle

Comment: You could read them in as elements of a list within a loop and then use bind_rows() to stick them together into one table, then just left_join once to that long df. I'm assuming you mean your dfs since the census ones do come already together. But it looks like your df does contain multiple states since you filter for STATE == i...

Comment: I am fairly new to R and have not used these sorts of functions like left_join or bind_rows. Could you show an example? My original thought was to add this line %mutate(pedestrian_variable=pedestrian_variable/state_pop)% to that first part of my code, but I do not see how to combine the census file into my code. @Elle

Comment: Well, once you've downloaded it you'll need to read it in using `pop = read.csv(...)` and then it could fit in between the select() and mutate(), so `select(...) %>% left_join(pop, by = c('STATE' = '`Geographic Area`') %>% mutate(rate = PEDS/2019) %>% mutate(date...)`. (Geographic Area and 2019 look to be the relevant names in the census data I downloaded, replace if needed.)

Comment: Or to save processing time you could do the left_join and some of your other operations before you enter the loop, so `df <- read.csv(...) %>% left_join(pop, by = c('STATE' = 'Geographic Area')) %>% mutate(rate = PEDS/2019) %>% mutate(date...)`

Comment: The first method is giving me a lot of errors and is indeed taking a little more time to process, so I tried the second method but do you mean I add it to the single like that is df <- read.csv("accident.csv")  or to df1<- df %>% ? Because the second option would mean I was already in the loop and the first option doesn't seem to work! @Elle

Comment: Yes, to df <- read.csv(). It should work—what errors are you getting? Have you read in the census data as 'pop', and checked the column names?

Comment: It says: Error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `Geographic Area`. Do you advise I simplify the csv just to have two columns (Geographic Area and 2019) and try again? @Elle

Comment: Does the file you read in contain the columns Geographic Area and 2019? You may need to put backticks around Geographic Area when you're working with it (because it contains a space), and 2019 might read in with an X before it.

Comment: The file does, but I think because in the census file it actually has state names and in mine is has state numbers that might be causing the issue? I am trying to recreate pop and see if that helps @Elle

Comment: Yeah, join on STATENAME instead of STATE.

Comment: Although, if i do this wouldn't that not work because what the census file has is one value per state but my original file has minutley data, so it wont know how to compress values if it can't span the dataframe I have, if so maybe i need to go back and try the first option? Because I need the data to be mutated into a time series and then combined by date and state and that only starts occuring in the loop @Elle

Comment: They don't need to have the same number of rows, the left_join will add the pop data frame to every row that matches each state. So if ALABAMA is there 100 times it'll join <alabama's population>> to each of those rows.

Comment: Yes I would imagine so.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have revised all peds with the label rate and I see the change in value. Just a question about presentation, I see my values are now in the form 5.231e-05. Is there a nicer way to convert this number so that any one seeing it on a graph could make sense of it? @Elle

Comment: You can disable scientific notation with `scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)`, but probably the best option is to edit the rate calculation and make it 'rate per 10,000' or something like that.

Comment: ahh so mutate(rate = (PEDS/2019)*100,000). The values are still like "0.0001989" but I guess this can't be fixed since it has to do with the data possibly! I just wanted to get the values to look like something a non-researcher would be able to understand hm @Elle

Comment: You could try looking at the range of your data to come up with a suitable scale factor, whether it's rate per thousand or rate per million etc.

Comment: I will, thank you so much for the help and guidance! @Elle

Comment: You're welcome, good luck. I'll collate this into an answer tomorrow so you can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collating my answers from the comments: you need to get state population data from an outside source such as the US Census https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-state-total.html#par_textimage_1574439295, read it in, join it to your dataset, and then calculate rate as pedestrians per population, scaled for ease of reading on the graph. You can make your code faster by taking some of your calculations out of the loop. The code below assumes the census data is called 'census.csv' and has columns 'Geographic Area' for state and 'X2019' for the most recent population data available.

```
pop <- read.csv('census.csv')
df <- read.csv('accidents.csv') %>% 
   left_join(pop, by = c('STATENAME' = 'Geographic Area') %>% 
   mutate(rate = (PEDS / X2019) * <scale>) %>%
   mutate(date = as.Date(as.character(paste(YEAR, MONTH, DAY, sep = "-"),"%Y-%m-%d")))
```

The left_join will match state names and give each row a population value depending on its state, regardless of how many rows there are.